# Why does my TOR exit node say "Unknown country"?

Tags: anonymity, security

I read one other post similar to my question, but it does not tell me if it is SAFE to use an exit node that comes from an "Unknown country".  Is it safe???

Comment: [GeoIP is bullshit](https://github.com/epidemics-scepticism/tor-misconception#geoip-is-bullshit).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is safe. I'm not sure what would make you think having an unknown location is unsafe.

Comment: Because for all I know "Unknown country" could be an NSA building anywhere on the planet....

Comment: The NSA can set up servers in any country, unknown or not.